# Equation for Turning Projectile

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, velocity, rotation, free-fall

I'm trying to cook up an equation that will give me position for a projectile which operates in the Newtonian Domain. So a the fall equation is:

$$\mathbf{p_t} = \frac{\mathbf gt^2}{2} + \mathbf{v_0}t +\mathbf{p_0}$$

Where:

- $\mathbf{p_t}$ is the unknown position at $t$
- $\mathbf g$ is a vector with a -9.8 vertical component
- $t$ is the given time
- $\mathbf{v_0}$ is the projectile velocity at time 0
- $\mathbf{p_0}$ is the projectile position at time 0

I've added terminal velocity into the equation (but not drag):

$$\mathbf{p_t} = \frac{\mathbf gt_\alpha^2}{2} + \mathbf{v_0}t_\alpha +\mathbf{p_0} + \mathbf{\Omega}t_\beta$$

Where:

- $t_\alpha$ is the time till terminal velocity
- $t_\beta$ is the time after terminal velocity
- $\|\mathbf{\Omega}\|$ is given and $\mathbf{\Omega} = \mathbf gt_\alpha + \mathbf{v_0}$ when $\|\mathbf{\Omega}\| = \|\mathbf gt_\alpha + \mathbf{v_0}\|$

But now I want to write an equation for a projectile that turns relative to it's speed. So for example the projectile will alter it's course down $\frac{\|\mathbf gt_\alpha + \mathbf{v_0}\|}{\|\mathbf{\Omega}\|}0.01 radians$. What I'm struggling with is that this change will effect the fall time so I can't create an equation that can reliably model $\mathbf{P_t}$. Is this something I have to use an approximation to find?

Comment: I am confused about your "terminal velocity" term. As long as you have the acceleration of gravity, the projectile will continue to accelerate with your form. What am I missing?

Comment: @Floris The acceleration due to gravity is applied for the duration of $t_\alpha$ then for $t_\beta$ only the velocity $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is applied. Basically I'm trying to sat $t_\alpha + t_\beta = t$. Is that clear?

Comment: You cannot first ignore drag and the make it magically re-appear as some terminal velocity term, it *really* doesn't work like that. So $\mathbf{p_t} = \frac{\mathbf gt_\alpha^2}{2} + \mathbf{v_0}t_\alpha +\mathbf{p_0} + \mathbf{\Omega}t_\beta$ is gibberish. If the question doesn't get voted down I'll show you how it's done.

Comment: @Gert Yup, I'm with you. This is a simplification. But then that's when a Newtonian fall equation is as well, a simplification. Eventually I will go put drag into the model, but for now I simply needed an upper bound for my turning ratio.

Comment: I highly recommend using a numerical approach and including drag. It is not hard.

Comment: @Floris As I mentioned I intend to add it, but I wanted to incorporate the turning mechanism first. If I can't accomplish that my models borked anyway and it doesn't much matter whether it has drag. If you're saying the turning thing "isn't hard" feel free to post an answer including the drag in the equation. That's what I'm ultimately going for anyway.

Comment: @JonathanMee: a change in direction is also an acceleration and thus also requires a force. You need to incorporate that force in your equations of motion. Trying to do it any other way is to leave Newtonian mechanics. Good luck with that. :) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

Comment: @Gert Funny you should mention that link, I'd begun reading over that, however it doesn't contain any information on a projectile that turns, in fact I can't find *any* information on a projectile that turns.

Comment: @JonathanMee: it turns all the time: it changes direction, that's turning is it not?

Comment: @Gert Nope that would be simple. I'm trying to model something that turns because of it's shape, for example a paper airplane with the that loops back on itself. Or a "sinker" thrown by a pitcher. Again I'm making a simplification but how could I model the projectile internally turning it's velocity downward?

Comment: @JonathanMee: for a plane the rudder provides that force that makes the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ change direction. Not easy to model. A 'sinker' is caused by spin imposed on the ball by the pitcher, much harder to model.

Comment: @Gert Thankfully what I want to model is far simpler than an airplane or a curveball. Just a .001 Radian downward turn. Of course that in and of itself may be too complex. Obviously I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the position is the integral of the velocity - this is the essence of the equation you wrote down (without the "terminal velocity" part which makes no sense).

If, at a certain time, you change the velocity (direction), you can just treat that point as the start of a new trajectory: the initial velocity will be "the velocity of the turned projectile", the initial position will be "the position when the projectile turned", and the rest of your equation is basically unchanged.

If you make just a small change in direction (in your example, 0.01 rad) that is quite straightforward. If you intend for the projectile to execute a longer arc, things become more complicated - but again, you can just add an acceleration vector perpendicular to the instantaneous velocity in order to describe this. So instead of just $\mathbf{g}$, you would have $\mathbf{g+a}$ where $\mathbf{a}$ is pointing toward the center of rotation of the arc.

Comment: Right I agree with that. So our equation looks like: $$\mathbf{p_t} = \frac{\mathbf gt_\alpha^2}{2} + \mathbf{v_0}t_\alpha + \mathbf{p_0} - (\mathbf gt_\alpha + \mathbf{v_0})\tan(.01)t_\alpha^2 + \mathbf{\Omega}t_\beta - \mathbf{\Omega}\tan(.01)t_\beta^2$$ As in we are using I should be using acceleration?